# converting rows to a table where there are duplicate timestamps

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

So I need to take some PowerShell (vmware statistics) output and format it like Vcenter used to when using the GUI so our reporting can be automated (currently it's a manual download task across 11 different VCs).

Here's an example of what I want:

```html
Time                cpu.usagemhz.average    cpu.usage.average
14/09/2021 14:00    28334                   2.46
14/09/2021 16:00    33152                   2.88
14/09/2021 18:00    37259                   3.24
14/09/2021 20:00    32789                   2.85
14/09/2021 22:00    26858                   2.33
15/09/2021 00:00    21091                   1.83
```

Here's what I'm doing:

```html
$CPUstats = 'cpu.usagemhz.average','cpu.usage.average'
$start = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
$results=Get-Stat -Entity $cluster -Stat $CPUstats -Start $start -IntervalMins 120 -MaxSamples 5 |  
    sort-object timestamp | Select-Object timestamp,value,unit,metricid
$results | ft
```

which spits out:

```html
Timestamp           Value Unit MetricId            
---------           ----- ---- --------            
03/08/2022 03:00:00 14787 MHz  cpu.usagemhz.average
03/08/2022 03:00:00 13.41 %    cpu.usage.average   
03/08/2022 05:00:00 13893 MHz  cpu.usagemhz.average
03/08/2022 05:00:00  12.6 %    cpu.usage.average   
03/08/2022 07:00:00 13345 MHz  cpu.usagemhz.average
03/08/2022 07:00:00  12.1 %    cpu.usage.average   
03/08/2022 09:00:00 14454 MHz  cpu.usagemhz.average
03/08/2022 09:00:00  13.1 %    cpu.usage.average   
03/08/2022 11:00:00 15575 MHz  cpu.usagemhz.average
03/08/2022 11:00:00 14.12 %    cpu.usage.average
```

As you can see I've got multiple timestamps and I want to put cpu.usagemhz.average and cpu.usage.average  result for each matching timestamp in one row (not column).  Just not sure how to PowerShell that (or if there's a way with get-stat that I'm not seeing?).

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`Group-Object` is useful for slicing & dicing.

A function to generalize this might be more useful. Meanwhile,

```
$results | Group-Object -Property TimeStamp | Select `
  @{ n="Time"; e={$_.Name} },
  @{ n="cpu.usagemhz.average"; e={ ($_.Group | ? {$_.MetricId -eq "cpu.usagemhz.average"}).Value } },
  @{ n="cpu.usage.average"; e={ ($_.Group | ? {$_.MetricId -eq "cpu.usage.average"}).Value } }
```